# I am able to retrieve the artist, name and genre from the database but not the price. What should the code be to retrieve the price?

Tags: c#, sql, database

This is an example of one of the buttons. [I am able to retrieve the artist, name and genre from the database but not the price. What should the code be to retrieve the price? I have set the price datatype to `varchar(50)` in the database then tried the decimal and int and non of them work

```
protected void btnSong6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = "In the end";
    Product Music = new Product();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string SelectCommand = "select Genre,Name,Artist, Price from Music WHERE name = '" + Name + "' ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectCommand, con);
    SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    read.Read();

    Music.Artist = read["artist"].ToString();
    Music.Name = read["name"].ToString();
    Music.Genre = read["genre"].ToString();
    Music.Price= read["price"].ToString();
    //ADD PRICE!!
    listMusic.Items.Add(Music.Genre + " : " + Music.Artist + " - " + Music.Name);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check the `Product` object and see if the definition for `Price` is decimal or not.  I would suggest that you set the type of your `Price` field in the database to an equivalent type (i.e. decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, you are not using 'price' for anything though. Not exactly sure what you would like to do with 'price, maybe add it to 'listMusic'?

If 'Music.Price'is a decimal you will need to convert it:

```
Music.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(read["price"]);
```

Then add it to 'listMusic':

```
 listMusic.Items.Add(Music.Genre + " : " + Music.Artist + " - " + Music.Name  + " $" + Music.Price);
```

You should also consider changing your database 'price' column to Decimal. Above code should work either way.

To reduce the amount of type conversions required when retrieving column values have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) article. [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader(v=vs.110).aspx) provides a series of methods allowing you to access column values in their native data types.

Something like:

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string SelectCommand = "select Genre,Name,Artist, Price from Music WHERE Name = '" + Name + "' ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectCommand, con);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (read.HasRows)
            {

                while (read.Read())
                {
                    Music.Genre = read.GetString(0);
                    Music.Name = read.GetString(1);
                    Music.Artist = read.GetString(2);
                    Music.Price = read.GetDecimal(3);

                    listMusic.Items.Add(Music.Genre + " : " + Music.Artist + " - " + Music.Name + " $" + Music.Price);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am sorry I should've mentioned that in the code above. I have added it to the listMusic, but the error is in: 
Music.Price= read["price"].ToString();

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type string to decimal

Comment: That solves the error, but it still wouldn't display the price with or without the ToString().

Comment: Yes in listMusic and I have added it already in my listMusic istMusic.Items.Add(Music.Genre + " : " + Music.Artist + " - " + Music.Name + " " + Music.Price);

Comment: You mean changing it to decimal in the database and then adding it to the listMusic?

Comment: It gives an error when I try to display them in the listbox 
Error: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
in your code you changed:
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

into this:
string constr = Settings.Default.connection;

If I did the same it would give an error at settings saying:
Error: The name settings doesnot exist in the current context

Comment: @mahmoudahmed : Fixed the connection string and removed my previous comments, sorry about that.. It is possible that the price returned from your query can not be converted to decimal. You can use decimal.TryParse to avoid errors if this is the case. see code in my answer.

Comment: That works but it gives me the price value to be zero. It doesnot retrieve the actual price from the database,

Comment: @mahmoudahmed : How does the price look in you database? It cannon be converted to decimal, maybe it contains an invalid character?

Comment: @mahmoudahmed : Remove the '$', you can add this later when you display the price.

Comment: I did but still the same issue. It wouldn't display

Comment: @mahmoudahmed : Change the Price column to decimal (in your Database).If that doesnt work, debug your application and have a look at 'read["price"].ToString()', make sure it is a valid number

Comment: Casting the type in the application is bad practice - the field in the database should be correct in the first instance.

Comment: @Paul  : I suggested that in my answer (right at the bottom),  reader.read[] returns an object hence the cast.  Updated my answer to suggest an alternative. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Ok it has finally worked. I changed the price to decimal(18,2) and removed the $ from the table data.
Thank you @Calvin